# Replace the last part of a string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I want to replace the last String which is a `,` with `)`.

Suppose the string is:

> Insert into dual (name,date,

It is to be converted to:

> Insert into dual (name,date)

Comment: Have you considered rewriting your loop so the right amount of commas show up?  I've seen a Stackoverflow question for getting exactly that loop as efficient as possible.

Comment: Simply use: "Insert into dual (name,date,".replaceAll(",(?!.*,)",")");

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The following code should replace the last occurrence of a `','` with a `')'`.

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(yourString);
b.replace(yourString.lastIndexOf(","), yourString.lastIndexOf(",") + 1, ")" );
yourString = b.toString();
```

**Note**  This will throw Exceptions if the `String` doesn't contain a `','`.

Comment: I think he tagged it as java, isn't stringbuilder a dotnet ?

Comment: Both languages have StringBuilder

Comment: 10x, didn't know that. I think that your solution will replace any last , and not only if it's in the end of the string.

Comment: Yeah, my solution will replace the last occurrence of a string even if it isn't the exact last character.

Comment: Dani: StringBuilder in Java is the non-thread safe variant of StringBuffer which makes it noticeably faster (if I remember correctly, about 20-30%) and should be preferred if the thread safe StringBuffer isn't explicitly needed.

Comment: heh... thats sick. i thought that was C# at first. only difference is the capitalization of the methods, really.

Comment: @Mark, yup.  They are very very similar.

Comment: using a regex is quicker

Answer (score 42):

You can use a regular expression:

```
String aResult = "Insert into dual (name,date,".replaceAll(",$", ")");
```

`replaceAll(...)` will match the string with the given regular expression (parameter 1) (in this case we match the last character if it is a comma). Then replace it with a replacement (parameter 2) (in this case is '`)`').

**Plus!** If you want to ensure that trailing spaces and tabs are taken care of, you can just change the regular expression to '`,\[ \t\]*$`'. Note: '`\[`' and '`\]`' is without backslash (I don't know how to properly escape it).

Comment: If you use replaceAll(",$", ")") as replaceAll("[,]*$", ")") , it will work although it has several commas. For ex; " (name, date,,," --> " (name, date)". I think this is more flexible.

Answer (score 20):

This is a custom method to replace only the last substring of a given string. It would be useful for you:

```
private String replaceLast(String string, String from, String to) {
    int lastIndex = string.lastIndexOf(from);
    if (lastIndex < 0)
        return string;
    String tail = string.substring(lastIndex).replaceFirst(from, to);
    return string.substring(0, lastIndex) + tail;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
str = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(",")) + ")";
```

Comment: That would change the last ",", indiscriminate if it is the last character in a String or not.

Comment: It works wherever ',' is located - it will ignore anything that follows the last ',' though.

Comment: An exception will be thrown by `substring` if `lastIndexOf` returns `-1`.

Answer (score 9):

Use [Apache Commons'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons) StringUtils function [removeEnd()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#removeEnd-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```java
StringUtils.removeEnd("www.domain.com", ".com")   = "www.domain"
```

Answer (score 2):

The more readable way ... Which you can use to learn about String and its functions

```
String myString = "Insert into dual (name,date,";
String newString = "";
int length = myString.length();
String lastChar = myString.substring(length-1);

if (lastChar.contains(",")) {
    newString = myString.substring(0,length-1) + ")";
}

System.out.println(newString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of the string, check the last character (if you have the length it is easy), and replace it - when necessary.

This solution is not language-specific - just use common sense.

Comment: Its not the last character, its the last occurrence of a specific character.

Comment: Well, the question isn't clear about that. "the last string.." I wonder what he meant...

Comment: True, that's why I went for the method that would work in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

On a similar search I found this answer:

*[Replace Last Occurrence of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665387/replace-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string/37066403#37066403)*

I think it is the best, because it uses the Java methods as intended rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

It essentially reads the string backwards and uses the String object's replaceFirst method, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Here is the documentation on replaceFirst String method and the StringBuffer's reverse function:

*[replaceFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)*

*[reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#reverse--)*

Here is how I implemented it to simply remove some HTML 'pre' tags from a code snippet that I wanted to interpret. Remember to reverse your search string as well, and then reverse everything back to normal afterwards.

```
private String stripHtmlPreTagsFromCodeSnippet(String snippet) {
    String halfCleanSnippet = snippet.replaceFirst("<pre>", "");
    String reverseSnippet = new StringBuffer(halfCleanSnippet).reverse().toString();
    String reverseSearch = new StringBuffer("</pre>").reverse().toString();
    String reverseCleanSnippet = reverseSnippet.replaceFirst(reverseSearch, "");
    return new StringBuffer(reverseCleanSnippet).reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `(^.+)b(.+$)`

Example (Replace the last **b** character)

```
System.out.println("1abchhhabcjjjabc".replaceFirst("(^.+)b(.+$)", "$1$2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace the last character of your string by `)`:

```
str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1)+")";
```

Make sure your string is not empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can replace the last occurrence of a string in another string:

```
String yourString = "foo, foo, foo, bar!";

yourString = yourString.replaceAll("foo, (?!foo, )", "bar!, ");
```

The `(?!foo, )` ensures that there is no `foo,`  afterwards.

See [helpful article](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) and [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#Summary%20of%20regular-expression%20constructs) on regex for more info.

Answer (score -2):

What’s up with the hassle if you can just do the following?

```
word = (String) word.subSequence(0, word.length() -1);
```

This returns a new String without the last part of a String.