# in android application how to detect the occurence of substring in a text

Tags: android

I'm getting a  text extracted  from  qrcode from my application, but as I am using zxing library its putting an extra DEMO at the end. How to remove it from there?
I was trying this but it does not work:

```
String aboutText = (Global.text).toString();
aboutText = aboutText.replace("DEMO", " ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String.replace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) only takes chars as argument. Try [String.replaceFirst(String, String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
aboutText = aboutText.replaceFirst("DEMO", " ");
```

shout work. You can also take a look at [replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: ok iam able to sort out this one removing DEMO from the text generated..aboutText = aboutText.replaceFirst("DEMO", " ");...but it will replace DEMO from the text where ever it happens..want to remove it from end only..

Comment: You can write your own 'replaceLast' method... For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660034/replace-last-string/5254817#5254817

Comment: thnx fortega....but i m intrested in replacing the last occurence od the "DEMO" ..but unfortunately dere is no func called..replacelast()..neways thnx for the link..i'll try it..

Answer (score 0):

Here you are: [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). As for a newbie it will be quite helpful to learn more about strings in Java and the operations with them.

Comment: but i am stuck in the second part .... that is from the extracted text from qrcode...how can i distinguish b/w ,which is SMS,Email,URL etc..and perform actions accordingly...