# change the place of elements of binary value

Tags: java, binary

I have a String which contains a binary value ( 101101 ). now I want to check if the last letter is 1 and if so change it to 0 . how can I do that ?

Comment: What have you already tried, and in what way is this "changing the order" as per your title?

Comment: From what you describe, how is this any different from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660034/replace-last-part-of-string)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String result = "101101".substring(0,5) + "0";
```

why checking? The last character will always be 0, regardless if it was 1 or 0 before...

Comment: @matarsak Now what do you mean with *how can I remove it*?

Answer (score 3):

You can write

```
int i = 0b101101;
if (i & 1 != 0)
   i = i & ~1;
```

or much simpler

```
i &= ~1; // sets lowest bit to 0.
```

Comment: You could also use `i ^= 1`, assuming you keep the `i & 1 != 0` test.

Comment: I think your post is kind of misleading since it looks like you're trying to use the hex literal as a binary literal.

Comment: @João Correct, but with `&=` you don't need the test.

Comment: @DaoWen A binary literal is what I intended. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help the O.P. with the `String` he has at the moment. Maybe put this in there before your code: `String s = <your number>; int i = Integer.parseInt(s);` and this after your code: `s = Integer.toString(i);`

Answer (score 3):

Simple version;

```
String binary = "101101";

binary = binary.substring(0, binary.length() - 1) + "0";
```

Example [here](http://ideone.com/FUMeP).

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
    String k = "101101";

    System.out.println(k);

    int len = k.length();
    char[] charr = k.toCharArray();
    if(charr[len - 1] == '1') {
        charr[len - 1] = '0';
    }
    k = new String(charr);

    System.out.println(k);
```

Comment: You can remove the if statement. The last digit will always be `0`.

Comment: If you keep removing bits you have Andreas_D's solution. ;)

Comment: yeah, I also forgot to mention - beside being one possible, this is probably the worst solution to this problem... ever :)

Comment: that was the first post that I saw , now how can I remove the last character ?

Comment: @matarsak Why do you want to remove the last character? Everyone has answered your initial question. Are you suggesting that you want something else now?

Answer (score 1):

```
int binary = 0b101101;

if ( binary % 2 != 0 )
{
    binary = binary ^ 1b;
}
```