# Java : how to replace my last char in a string

Tags: java

I am trying to replace the last char in my String .

```
String bowlNumber = 1.1;

bowlNumber.replace(bowlNumber.charAt(bowlNumber.length-1), 2);
```

By this I am able to replace my last character i.e 1  to   2..
 but the problem is as my first character is also 1 , it also changes that to 2.

What i want is to  change 1.1   to  1.2 ,  but it makes 1.1  to  2.2

Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660034/replace-last-part-of-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
bowlNumber = bowlnNumber.substring(0,bowlNumber.length()-1) + "2";
```

Comment: Should be `bowlNumber.length()` as length is a function.

Comment: Wrong output. It will print only 12 not 1.2.

Comment: true ... true ... i wrote it in a hurry just as an ideea... i think i've corrected now...

Answer (score 3):

```
String bowlNumber="1.1";
String replaceEnd = bowlNumber.replaceAll(".$", "2");
System.out.println(replaceEnd);
```

The OutPut is: 
1.2

Answer (score 3):

Try following code:

```
    String bowlNumber = "1.1";
    bowlNumber=bowlNumber.substring(0, bowlNumber.length()-1)+"2";
    System.out.println(bowlNumber);
```

**Output**

1.2