# Replace Last Occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: java, string

I am having a string like this

```
"Position, fix, dial"
```

I want to replace the last double quote(") with escape double quote(\")

The result of the string is to be

```
"Position, fix, dial\"
```

How can I do this. I am aware of replacing the first occurrence of the string. but don't know how to replace the last occurrence of a string

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
String str = "\"Position, fix, dial\"";
int ind = str.lastIndexOf("\"");
if( ind>=0 )
    str = new StringBuilder(str).replace(ind, ind+1,"\\\"").toString();
System.out.println(str);
```

**Update**

```
 if( ind>=0 )
    str = new StringBuilder(str.length()+1)
                .append(str, 0, ind)
                .append('\\')
                .append(str, ind, str.length())
                .toString();
```

Comment: Just asking. Why not like this?
`String str = "\"Position, fix, dial\"";
str.replaceAll("[\"]\\Z", "\"");
System.out.println(str);`

Comment: yes, you can use something like **str = str.replaceAll("[\"]\\Z", "\\\\\"")**. But it will replace the last quot at the end of input. it wont work for < **"Position, fix, dial" again** >.

Comment: @Dudeist because that's much less readable.

Answer (score 62):

This should work:

```
String replaceLast(String string, String substring, String replacement)
{
  int index = string.lastIndexOf(substring);
  if (index == -1)
    return string;
  return string.substring(0, index) + replacement
          + string.substring(index+substring.length());
}
```

This:

```
System.out.println(replaceLast("\"Position, fix, dial\"", "\"", "\\\""));
```

Prints:

```
"Position, fix, dial\"
```

[Test](https://ideone.com/Up0yvv).

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer because it is general purpose.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to remove the las character (in case there is one) this is a one line method. I use this for directories.

```
localDir = (dir.endsWith("/")) ? dir.substring(0,dir.lastIndexOf("/")) : dir;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String docId = "918e07,454f_id,did";
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(docId);
docId = buffer.reverse().toString().replaceFirst(",",";");
docId = new StringBuffer(docId).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: This only works for single character things.