# What is regex for replacing &f afrer same

Tags: java, regex

I have string like this:

```
Hello &f are &f you &f here?
```

And I want to replace only last &f with "" (by last I mean third one, which is near "here". I tried something like this:

```
"Hello &f are &f you &f here?".replaceAll(".&f", "")
```

But it doesn't work, so could someone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665387/replace-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also be done with `StringBuilder.reverse()`

```
String str1 = "Hello &f are &f you &f here ?";
String temp = new StringBuilder(str1).reverse().toString().replaceFirst("f&", "");
String rslt = new StringBuilder(temp).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(rslt);
```

Steps:

1. Reverse the String using StringBuffer
2. Replace first `f&` with the help of `String.replaceFirst()`
3. Then again reverse that String.

Output:

```
Hello &f are &f you  here ?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String s = "Hello &f are &f you &f here?";
    s = s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf("&f")) + s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("&f")+3);
    System.out.println("s = " + s); // prints: s = Hello &f are &f you here?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
(.*)&f
```

And replace with the backreference `$1`. (Or is it `\1` in Java?)

http://regex101.com/r/qG0fM9