# How do I remove a repeating characted in my string and trim the white spaces within a string in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have to test few 10 digit values.

```
          Value: 124324*3213*4324*44*3123**13*
         Expected value: 1243243213432444312313
```

So far, I have been able to replace the stars using str.replace() function. But I'm unable to remove the white spaces created after removing the star ?.

Comment: How are you removing the *'s?

Comment: Please add the code you've tried. To replace something by removing it instead of adding space try: str.replace('*', '');

Comment: Using this:

value = value.replace(value.charAt(lastIndexof('*'),'\u0000');

Comment: So you only need the asterisk(*) characters removed not the duplicate numbers also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that strings are immutable in Java so you have to assign value again:

```
String s = "124324*3213*4324*44*3123**13*";
s = s.replaceAll("\\*", "");
```

"\\*" - is a regular expression, but you don't need to worry about that. The important part is that "*" sign has special meaning in regular expressions, so you have to escape it with a backslash. To create a backslash character in Java string you have to use "\\" - so the final expression is "\\*".

Comment: s = s.replace("*", ""); would also suffice

Comment: @Taelsin you're right, perhaps using a regular expression is a bit too complicated for such simple task.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, is there a way I can remove only the last occurence of *. Like removing the index of that *.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
String value = "124324*3213*4324*44*3123**13*".replace("*", "");
```

Comment: @GauthamHonnavara Have you tried it? Have you looked at the docs?

Comment: No, `String.replace` method allows `char` or `CharSequence` parameters: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. Thanks a ton. But, could you please tell me is charSequence considered a string.

Comment: Also, is there a way to just remove the last occurence of *(something like the last index) but keep the remaining ones.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665387/replace-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string