# String replace method issue in java

Tags: java, string, replace

My problem is to replace only the last occurrence of a character in the string with another character. When I used the String.replace(char1, char2), it replaces all the occurrences of the character in the string.

For example, I have an address string like

`String str = "Addressline1,Addressline2,City,State,Country,";`.

I need to replace the occurrence of ',' at the end of the string with '.'.

My code to replace the character is

```
str = str.replace(str.charAt(str.lastIndexOf(",")),'.');
```

After replacing, the string looks like:

**Addressline1.Addressline2.City.State.Country.**

Is there the problem in Java SDK?. If yes, how to resolve it?

Comment: No, `#replace` takes a character argument and replaces it with the second. You've effectively said "find the character at the place where the character is `,`, and then replace all of those characters with `.`"

Comment: try this<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665387/replace-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string>.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion over what you want.  Do you want to (1) replace the last character of the string with `.`, no matter what it is; (2) replace the last character of the string with `.` only if it's a comma; or (3) replace the last _comma_ in the string with `.` even if there are characters following the comma?

Comment: @suku, I need a solution for this problem in java not in javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Java [replace function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) has a method declaration of:

```
public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
```

According to the docs `replace` will:

> Return a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of `oldChar` in this string with `newChar`.

So your code:

```
str.charAt(str.lastIndexOf(","))
```

Will clearly return the character `,`. `replace` will then replace all instances of the `oldChar` `,` with the `newChar` `.`. This explains the behavior you were seeing.

The solution that @ScaryWombat beat me to is your best option:

```
str = str.replaceAll(",$", ".");
```

Since, in regular expression terms, `$` denotes the end of a String.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You should use `String.replaceAll` which use regex

```
str = str.replaceAll (",$", ".");
```

The `$` mean the end of the String

Comment: I don't think this is right.  Looking at what the OP is trying to do, I think he's trying to replace the last comma in the string, _even if the comma is not the last character of the string_.  Your code doesn't do that.  On the other hand, he just approved your answer while I was typing this comment, so maybe it really is what he wants.

Comment: @ajb `I need to replace the occurrence of ',' at the end of the string with '.'.`

Comment: OK, I see that the OP sort of contradicted himself.