# Java Formatting String to replace Special Character

Tags: java, string

I have String like this:

```
String strCustom1 = "Red, Green, Blue";
```

I have tried this, but replacing all the `,` with `and`

```
    strCustom = "Red, Green, Blue";
    strCustom = strCustom.replaceAll(",",  " and");

    [or]

    strCustom = strCustom.replace(",",  " and");
```

Like this:

```
    Red and Blue and Green
```

But I just want to **replace** last `,` with `space+and`

So it should look this:

```
    Red, Green and Blue
```

In a same way, want to format this:

```
    String strCustom2 = "Red, Green, Blue, Yellow";
```

and as a result i want to get this:

```
    Red, Green, Blue and Yellow
```

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1660047/1737819 how to replace last occurence of the string.

Comment: Question needs thorough study of String manipulation method, regular expressions and String builder. Actually not much effort needed to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
strCustom = strCustom.substring(0, strCustom.lastIndexOf(",")) + " and" + strCustom.substring(strCustom.lastIndexOf(",") + 1);
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works :) i ticked as useful and will share after 9 mins and can you brief me use of strCustom.substring(strCustom.lastIndexOf(",") + 1);

Comment: @Oreo The `substring(int index)` will create a `String` that starts from `index` and ends at the original `String` end. In this example I've included `+ 1` so that the substring start after the last `,` character.

Comment: P1. Better to store `strCustom.lastIndexOf(",")` in `int` instead of calling it twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this..

```
String strCustom = "Red, Green, Blue";
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(strCustom);
sb.replace(strCustom.lastIndexOf(","),strCustom.lastIndexOf(",")+1," and");
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Out put:

```
Red, Green and Blue
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick regex will do it for you :

```
    public static void main(String arf[]) {
        String strCustom1 = "Red, Green, Blue";
        System.out.println(strCustom1.replaceAll(",(?=\\s\\w+$)"," and" )); // find the last ",".
    }
```

O/P:

```
Red, Green and Blue
```