# Replace special chars with regex Java

Tags: java, regex

Looking for some help to find how to replace the last "." char to some other string via regex in java. I have code something like this which doesn't work. Any advise.

```
"//myserver.com//NAGA.CSV".replaceAll(".$","_2.")
```

**Output:** //myserver.com//NAGA_2.CSV

Comment: [`"//myserver.com//NAGA.CSV".replaceFirst("""\.(?!.*\.)""","_2.")`](https://ideone.com/JTalEH)

Comment: Also [Replace last part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660034/replace-last-part-of-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a lookahead,  to find the end of the string, preceded by characters other than dot.

```
yourString.replaceAll("\\.(?=[^.]*$)", "replacement");
```

Note that the first dot needs to be escaped with a backslash, because dot has a special meaning in a regular expression (it matches any character).  The second dot doesn't need to be escaped, because the special meaning doesn't apply in square brackets.

The `(?=   )` structure means "followed by this" - in other words, the dot that you match can be followed by any number of non-dot characters, and then the end of the string.  Those extra characters are not considered part of the match.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a regex, but you could use the `String.lastIndexOf()` method to get the position of the last occurence of your char and use `String.substring` to create your new String:

```
String yourString = "test.csv";
String newValue = "_2.";
int lastOccurence = yourString.lastIndexOf(".");
String replacedString = yourString.substring(0, lastOccurence) + newValue + yourString.substring(lastOccurence + 1);
```